# webRTC - disable media sent to remote peer but not local media

Tags: webrtc

I am trying to be able to disable(blank video and silent audio) that is being sent to the other peer while keep local media enabled.

I want to have call answer or reject buttons. But I don't want wait for callee to press 'answer' button before I can send out the media which causes a bit delay before media appears on screen. I know I can listen to `iceState` and show video only when it is `connected` or `completed` but I think user clicking answer button generally gives connection more time to finish doing thing so I am assured that generally media connection will be already set up before they 'accept' the call.

For this, I will send media but disabled and when 'answer' button is pressed I will enable the media being sent.

I am trying this below code to disable media but it does it for local media as well.

```
document.getElementById("local_video").srcObject = webcamStream;

webcamStream.getTracks().forEach(
    function (track){
        myPeerConnection.addTrack(track, webcamStream);
    });

function initialMediaMuted(){
    let videoTrackBlank;
    let audioTrackBlank;
    myPeerConnection.getSenders().find(function (s) {
        if (s.track.kind === "video") {
            videoTrackBlank = s.track;
        }
        if (s.track.kind === "audio") {
            audioTrackBlank = s.track;
        }
    });
    videoTrackBlank.enabled = false;
    audioTrackBlank.enabled = false;
}
```

Can anyone please guide me how can I adjust it to keep local media enabled but outgoing media disabled?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the same `MediaStreamTrack` instance for both local display and streaming. If you call [`MediaStreamTrack.clone()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack/clone) to create a copy before calling `addTrack`, you can set the enabled state separately.

```
webcamStream.getTracks().forEach(
    function (track){
        const cloneTrack = track.clone();
        myPeerConnection.addTrack(cloneTrack, webcamStream);
        cloneTrack.enabled = false;
    });
```

Comment: Yes, I managed it that way. Thank you. I will accept your answer